# Using `subset()` within a secondary R function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, subset

When requested, function `foo1` can `subset` a list `by` a desired variable (e.g., `by = ESL == 1`). Otherwise, `foo1` will simply output the inputted list itself.

For my purposes, I need to use `foo1` within a new function called `foo2`. **BUT** I'm wondering why `foo2` fails and how to fix it:

`Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'ESL' not found`

The full reproducible data and code is below:

```
foo1 <- function(by, data){

L <- split(data, data$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL

 if(!missing(by)){

 s <- substitute(by)    

 H <- lapply(L, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, s)))

 L <- Filter(nrow, H)
   }
return(L)
}

## EXAMPLE OF USE:
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/k.csv", h = T) ## Data

foo1(data = D, by = ESL == 1) ## works fine :-) @@@@

## BUT:
foo2 <- function(by, data){

  foo1(by = by, data = data)
}

## EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo2(data = D, by = ESL == 1) ## Fails :-( @@@@
```

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: It would be the env issue

Comment: @akrun, I see, but what is the alternative?

Comment: In the `foo2`, try `eval(substitute(fool1, by = by, data = data)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can modify the `foo2` to `eval`luate the function call

```
foo2 <- function(by, data){ 

  eval(substitute(foo1(by = by, data = data)))
 }

out1 <- foo1(data = D, by = ESL == 1) 
out2 <- foo2(data = D, by = ESL == 1) 
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```